# Enum for common names in Request.Form collection

Tags: asp.net

Does ASP.NET contains any enumerator for common field names used in Request.Form collection such as "_*EVENTTARGET" and "*_EVENTARGUMENT"? I need to refer to those names in multiple places in my app and I would love to be able to type something like `this.Page.Request[CommonRequestNames.EventTarget]` instead of hard-coding them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing like this built into the BCL.

Instead of an enum consider using a set of public constant strings.

The reason enums are a poor choice is that they can only be based on integral types (except `Char`), not strings and you would end up having to translate from enum value to enum name and back, which can get messy.

Comment: Thank you. Will use public constants instead.